# При анимации префаб поворачивается на 90 градусов. Как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d

Во время выполнение анимации, префаб поворачивается на 90 градусов (возвращается в исходное положение??) и после завершения анимации, возвращается в нормальное положение.

**Как воспроизвести анимацию, учитывая исходное положение префаба?** (т.е. чтоб анимация проигрывалась с учетом положения префаба в пространстве)

Код вызова анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Положение объектов ДО вызова анимации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Положение объектов ВО ВРЕМЯ вызова анимации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Анимация же статична... Она не может ничего учитывать. Вы можете сделать поворот кодом. Можно использовать DoTween или что-то такое

Answer (score 0):

Либо префаб, либо анимация (скорее всего последнее) неправильно повёрнуты. Посмотри ещё раз внимательно, чтобы и анимация, и префаб смотрели прямо, по синей стрелке.

Говорю, как человек, у которого тоже немного сломался мозг на этом когда-то.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Это именно ответ, поэтому опубликовал как ответ. Воть.